# .indexOf() equivalent in Neo4j Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nosql

No matter how I swing it, I need some kind of function to find the index of a item in an array supplied as a parameter.

I am trying to simply update items in a collection based on the index of one of their properties in an array, and have been poring through Cypher docs for nearly 2 hours...

It would also be acceptable to order the items by that array, and then run a foreach on the ordered list...

Comment: As you mentioned, you can sort your list with `WITH` and than collect it for your foreach. I think it is not possible to sort  collection other way. If you have collection created than you can `UNWIND` it, sort with `ORDER BY` and again `COLLECT()`

Comment: Can you show me the syntax?  Not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: you have some collection for example `person_col` than you will do `some code...`  
`WITH person_col`  
`UNWIND person_col as persons`  
`ORDER BY person.name asc`  
`COLLECT(persons) as person_col`  
and now you have your collection sorted, you can use foreach. I don't know if you want something like that.

Comment: I need it sorted by an array supplied as a parameter.  E.g., [4, 52, 35, 235] for Neo4j relationship IDs, I want them in that order.

Comment: djvs -- what is the parameter?  I get that you want to sort an array of IDs, but how did you know to arrive at that sort order?  What was the parameter and what did it mean?   Was the parameter an attribute value, or what?

Comment: The parameter comes from the application user, sorting a list of items.  There are no constraints on it.  

In the mean time I opted for the alternate approach, one separate query for each item. Not ideal but at least I know it'll almost never exceed 300ms.

Answer (score 1):

Following @stefan-armbruster answer and great blog post, a slow but simple **index_of** can be done with:

```
reduce(x=[-1,0], i IN [1,2,7,5,21,5,1,435] | 
    CASE WHEN i = 21 THEN [x[1], x[1]+1] ELSE [x[0], x[1]+1] END 
)[0]
```

Here `reduce` function works with a two elements array: the position and the current index. If an element in your array matches the given condition, the first element of the reduced array will be replaced with the current index.
I put an example on neo4j console http://console.neo4j.org/?id=34byv

Answer (score 0):

I've [blogged about that](http://blog.armbruster-it.de/2015/03/cypher-fun-finding-the-position-of-an-element-in-an-array/) recently. You can use the `reduce` function with an three element array as state variable containing

- the index of the highest occupation so far
- the current index (aka iteration number)
- the value of highest occupation so far

As an example to find the index of max element in an array:

```
RETURN reduce(x=[0,0,0], i IN [1,2,2,5,2,1] | 
    CASE WHEN i>x[2] THEN [x[1],x[1]+1,o] ELSE [x[0], x[1]+1,x[2]] END 
)[0]
```

Comment: I tried your blog post the night I posted this, it didn't seem to work (return anything), IIRC.

Comment: I wonder if you could tailor your code to the original requirement?  It has to "set" them with zero-based  i, i+1, in order of the supplied array.

Also FYI, I think you have a typo in one of the code sections (I think you mistake "i" for "o" or something).

Comment: don't quite understand your use case. With the snippet above you can grab the index of the largest element. Isn't that what you've asked for?

Comment: No, I'm looking for the placement of an item within an array ("indexOf").